# How can I set "mysql_default_charset" and "mysql_collate" for all tables globally in SQLAlchemy and not on a per-table basis using "__table_args__"?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I've been issues setting the "Character Set" and "Collation" for my tables in MySQL created using SQLAlchemy.

In particular, tables were always created using "latin1" for both the "Character Set" and "Collation".

Setting the "charset" in the URL, didn't solve the issue:

```
f'mysql+pymysql://{_user}:{_pwd}@{_host}:{_port}/{_db}?charset=utf8mb4',
```

Neither, did `create_engine(...,encoding='utf8')`.

Only by setting the following `__table_args__`, was the table created with support for UTF-8:

```
__table_args__ = (
    {'mysql_default_charset': 'utf8',
     'mysql_collate': 'utf8_bin'}
)
```

How can I set the above table arguments for **all** tables in the database without having to specify them explicitly as `__table_args__` for each of them?

**Full example**:

```
class Match(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'stash_match'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    blob_id = Column(String(40))
    text = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    regex = Column(Text, nullable=False)

    blob = relationship('Blob', back_populates='matches')

    __table_args__ = (
        ForeignKeyConstraint([blob_id], [Blob.id], onupdate='CASCADE', ondelete='CASCADE'),
        {'mysql_default_charset': 'utf8',
         'mysql_collate': 'utf8_bin'}
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

As described in the documentation [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html#augmenting-the-base) you can augment the declarative `Base` class to customize the default behaviour:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker

connection_uri = (
    "mysql+pymysql://root:toot@localhost:3307/mydb?charset=UTF8mb4"
)
engine = sa.create_engine(connection_uri, echo=True,)


class Base(object):
    __table_args__ = {
        "mysql_default_charset": "utf16",
        "mysql_collate": "utf16_icelandic_ci",
    }


Base = declarative_base(cls=Base)


class Team(Base):
    __tablename__ = "team"
    prov = sa.Column(sa.String(2), primary_key=True)
    city = sa.Column(sa.String(20), primary_key=True)
    team_name = sa.Column(sa.String(20))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Team(prov='{self.prov}', city='{self.city}')>"


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

The DDL that gets rendered is

```sql
CREATE TABLE team (
    prov VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL, 
    city VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    team_name VARCHAR(20), 
    PRIMARY KEY (prov, city)
)DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 COLLATE utf16_icelandic_ci
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is the `charset=UTF8mb4` in the `connection_uri` strictly necessary, if so why? It's the client charset AFAIK. Also, how would I handle multiple SQL backends (MySQL, MSSQL, etc.)? Would I need to create several `Base` classes, and then create and return the model classes from a function, depending on the selected `Base`? Please take a look at my question here, if you're interested: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/248183/providing-different-table-args-to-sqlalchemy-mapped-class-depending-on-backe?noredirect=1#comment486106_248183

Comment: Does MySQL always default to `latin1`?